# Accessing Return Values with COM using Python

Tags: python, com, ole

I am using Python with win32com to access COM objects. One of the COM objects is supposed to return another COM object but a tuple about the called method is returned instead.  Is there a way to access the returned data?

The statement which I programmed is:

item = server.OPCHDAItems.AddItem("TIC101",1)

item should be the object added, an OPCHDAItem.  When I print item I just get

<COMObject AddItem>

The item was added to the OPCHDAItems collection because I can see the size of the collection increasing.

From reading the docs about win32com is states taht a tuple is returned from a method call but I could not find how to access the return data from the method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but I think the OPCHDAItem has been added properly. The `print` is using the `__repr__` or the `__str__` method of the class for printing something. A COM class is automatically generated, so I guess these methods are not overloaded.

Try to generate the interface of the COM object with the MakePy utility (see http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html). It will create a file that contains the description of the COM object. In this file, you should see the list of attributes and methods of the objects.

I hope it helps